# Akka (JVM) initialize logger before ActorSystem

Tags: scala, logging, akka

I have an application that needs to call some external system (to decrypt sensitive information to keep it short) before being able to create the configuration that the actor system will use.

Is it possible to initialize the logger at the very beginning of my process so that the monitoring/investigation tools can access the logs in case the communication with the external system goes wrong ?

```
// the following call will modify the config from a secret id read in the conf
// and write the value "redis.password" after getting the value from an Azure Keyvault
val updatedConf = KeyVaultHelper.decryptFromKeyVault(ConfigFactory.load("application"),
  Map(
    "azure.keyvault.redis.password.secret-id",
    "redis.password"
  ))

// now we initialize the actor system with the updated conf
// and the logging system will be initialized
val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", updatedConf)
```

Comment: Could you post some code sample? It's really hard to tell, for the most pessimistic path I'd say to use an early initializer.

Comment: I just did, not sure if that helps ?

Comment: So you need to use the logger before creating the system. I'm not sure I understood correctly your use-case but I will paste some code below.

Comment: Also, are you trying to use the logger inside the `ActorSystem`? If not then you should be able to create a new logger before setting up the system.

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to log if anything goes wrong before the ActorSystem is created (which will also log if things went well of course).

Comment: If you want to use the ActorSystem's `log` you can't initialize it before it is created. You should set up another logger alternatively. I can provide an example of using a lightweight external library if you'd like :)

Comment: My concern is that I would like to avoid duplicating the logger configuration since logs are pushed to an external system when deployed in the cloud (to Azure Application Insights in my case). I guess I could initialize another actorsystem earlier but that seems heavy and dirty.

Comment: I put an example below that uses scala-logging. It's quite lightweight and should help you avoid any issues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use the [`akka-slf4j`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/logging.html#SLF4J) library along with their recommended logging backend [`logback`](http://logback.qos.ch/). Two things need to be configured.

The `logback.xml` file that configures the loggers:

```xml
<!-- src/main/resources/logback.xml -->
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %-5level %logger{36} %X{sourceThread} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

The slf4j logger must be configured from the typesafe config as well:

```
# src/main/resources/application.conf
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

Please see blow a code sample to test the configuration.

```scala
object LoggingTest extends App {
  // Do all decryption logging here
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
  logger.debug("Starting application. Decrypting info from config")

  // Now you boot the system which will use the same logging config
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val actor = system.actorOf(Props[Echo])

  actor ! "hello"
}

class Echo extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case message =>
      context.system.log.debug(s"echo $message")
  }
}
```

I've used the following `akka-actor` & `akka-slf4j` 2.4.17 and `ch.qos.logback` 1.1.3.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Yes sorry for not being crystal clear. I am using logback as logger for my actorsystem, and I would like to share its configuration with whatever I do if I try to log before the actorsystem exists. For the moment, the logger is initialized by Akka itself and I am not really sure how to initialize it. I guess it is actually quite straightforward what I want to do: just make sure that the logback logger I would create would use the same configuration.

Comment: It is possible If you use akka-slf4j. I will edit the answer after lunch :)

Comment: Please check the edit and let me know if it solves your issue :)

Comment: It seems perfect ! I will test that and accept your answer, thanks !!

Comment: Works fine, thanks again. This was much simpler than expected :-).